# как сделать прокрутку всего списка в android?

Tags: java, android

Есть список, не получается сделать прокрутку всего текста, когда ставлю LinerLayout, то все летит и вместо 2х столбцов получается один. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить исходный вид и добавить скроллинг.
[image: вот так должно быть]

Comment: Разметку покажите в XML, а не картинкой, пока мы не доросли до #nocode

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/scrollview.php